# Insert space between strings

Tags: awk, sed

I would  like to add a white space after the word transcript_id throughout the second column
  "Row.names"        "id"                     gene_id.x"

```
 "1"    transcript_id"TCONS_00000008"   "XLOC_000004"
 "2"    transcript_id"TCONS_00000015"   "XLOC_000005"
 "3"    transcript_id"TCONS_00000033"   "XLOC_000008"
 "4"    transcript_id"TCONS_00000037"   "XLOC_000008"
 "5"    transcript_id"TCONS_00000039"   "XLOC_000008"
```

and tried this

```
sed 's/./& /17' file.out > files.out
```

and it worked and the result looked like this

"Row.names"      "id"                     gene_id.x"

```
 "1"    transcript_id "TCONS_00000008"  "XLOC_000004"
 "2"    transcript_id "TCONS_00000015"  "XLOC_000005"
 "3"    transcript_id "TCONS_00000033"  "XLOC_000008"
 "4"    transcript_id "TCONS_00000037"  "XLOC_000008"
 "5"    transcript_id "TCONS_00000039"  "XLOC_000008"
```

But then when I checked the second column using

```
 awk '{ print $2 }'  files.out
```

I only get

```
transcript_id
transcript_id
transcript_id
transcript_id
transcript_id
```

For example, I want transcript_id "TCONS_00000008" in a single column and not split them into 2 and 3rd columns.

Comment: By any chance are your columns tab-separated (instead of plain spaces)? If so, after sed just invoke awk with `-F\t` and column 2 will be what you want. If not, you might think about using a different separator that will allow you to have spaces within columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "insert an space" in a field, the field will be split on that space by awk.
That is what you are experiencing.

To use a cleaned file we need to filter your source file to some temporal test file (all spaces and tabs replaced by one only space between fields):

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]\+//1' -e 's/[ \t]\+/ /g' originalfile >file.tmp
```

Use 20 or 50 lines if the original file is too big.

Then, Either you:

1. Choose to use some other delimiter for awk (not the default: space).
   You could

   - Split fields in awk on runs of two spaces or more: FS=' +'.
   - Split fields in awk on tab(s) FS='\t+'
   - Split fields in awk on comma FS=','

To filter the cleaned file:

```
sed -e 's/ /  /g' file.tmp > file2.tmp    ### replace a space with two spaces.
sed -e 's/ /\t/g' file.tmp > file2.tmp    ### replace a space with tab.
sed -e 's/ /,/g'  file.tmp > file2.tmp    ### replace a space with comma.
```

Insert **one** space (in-place edit of file2.tmp):

```
sed -ie 's/_id/& /1' file2.tmp
```

Then use awk with the new delimiter:

```
awk -F '[ ][ ]+' '{print $2}' file2.tmp      ### For runs of two or more spaces
awk -F '[\t]+' '{print $2}' file2.tmp        ### For runs of one or more tabs.
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' file2.tmp            ### For comma.
```

2. Insert some other character instead of space ([non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) `&nbsp;` maybe?). There are several other "spaces" in unicode, search wikipedia.

   ```
   sed -ie 's/_id/&\xC2\xA0/1' file2.tmp  ### nbsp is 0xC2 0xA0 in utf-8.
                                          ### change bytes for other encoding.  
   awk '{print $2}' file2.tmp             ### Works as the space is a "nbsp".
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The default field separator in **awk** matches on one or more tabs or spaces; so, the **sed** invocation has the effect of making an additional column.  You can change this behaviour though:

```
awk -F'  +' '{ print $2 }' files.out
```

This changes the field separator to match on two or more spaces.  If you want also to match on tab, you can change the field separator regular expression as follows:

```
awk -F'  +|[\t]+' '{ print $2 }' files.out
```

To implement the result without invoking **sed**:

```
awk '{ x=$2; sub(/"/, " \"", x); print x }' file.out
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about confusing anyone else you can use a non-breaking space.  For example

```
$ sed 's/_id/&\xA0/' file | awk '{print $2}'

transcript_id "TCONS_00000008"
transcript_id "TCONS_00000015"
transcript_id "TCONS_00000033"
transcript_id "TCONS_00000037"
transcript_id "TCONS_00000039"
```

However, a better approach is defining a field separator which is different (also visually) from the chars you're using in a field.

Comment: An "\xA0" is a valid `nbsp` in ISO-8859-1 and similar, but [not in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)